# GNU ls from Coreutils missing OS X ACL implementation

Tags: macos, bash, homebrew, ls, gnu-coreutils

I'm using `brew` to retrieve and install common GNU versions of terminal commands and utils with `brew install coreutils`.
Then in my .bash_profile I'm including their PATH with

```
if [  -d $(brew --prefix coreutils)/libexec/gnubin  ]; then
    PATH="$(brew --prefix coreutils)/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"
fi
```

so far so good, I can use use the GNU version of coreutils.
The problem comes from `ls`. Apple implement [ACL](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/apple-in-the-enterprise/introduction-to-os-x-access-control-lists-acls/) that is not implemented on GNU `ls`. I discovered this by banging my head many times and not understanding why (for example) `ls -le@` would give me error `ls: invalid option -- 'e'`.

So now I understood that GNU ls is the problem.

**QUESTION**:
how can I source all the coreutils BUT `ls`? 
I want to use the Apple version of `ls` but keep on using the rest of the coreutils. How can I achieve this modifying my `.bash_profile`?

**EDIT:**

If I create a flag to understand if I am currently using coretuils or not and as a consequence I'll create an alias:

```
ls_flag=false
if [[  $(brew) &&  -d  $(brew --prefix coreutils)/libexec/gnubin  ]]; then
    PATH="$(brew --prefix coreutils)/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"
    ls_flag=true
fi

export PATH

if [[ ls_flag -eq true ]]; then
   alias ls=/bin/ls
fi
```

This will work if I stop my `.bash_profile` here. But another problem arise from the following conditions. I use them to understand if I'm using the GNU ls or the Apple ls and chose the correct option to colorise the ls command:

```
# Detect which `ls` flavour is in use
if ls --color > /dev/null 2>&1; then # GNU `ls`
    alias ls='ls --color=always'
    # load my color scheme (it only works with GNU ls)
    # dircolors only work with coreutils
    eval `dircolors  ~/.dotfiles/data/dircolors`
else # OS X `ls`
    alias ls='ls -G'
fi
```

So, at this point ls should be:
1) alias ls=/bin/ls # from the 1st condition ls_flag == true
2) alias ls='ls -G' # from the 2nd condition "if ls --color" (false)

BUT if I prompt `ls -@` will still throw an error telling me that I'm still using the GNU ls...wondering why the last alias will override the previous ones...

Comment: Why don't you just remove (or rename, or `chmod -x`) coreutils' `ls`?

Comment: Another possibility is to link the coreutils commands you want to use (hence not `ls`) in your `/usr/local/bin` (or another directory that could be more appropriate on OSX), making sure this directory appears before `/bin` in your `PATH` variable.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I want to use all the commands (but ls) from coreutils, that is what `PATH="$(brew --prefix coreutils)/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"` will do. Manually linking all them but ls doesn't seems a good solution. Let's say there are 100 commands, instead of removing the only 1 I don't need you are suggesting to link the 99 I needs..to much work

Comment: Then how about my other suggestion? i.e., rename/remove/`chmod -x` the `ls` from coreutils?

Comment: Btw, linking all but one is rather easy: link them all, and remove the link for the one(s) you don't want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is wrong

```
if [[ ls_flag -eq true ]]; then
   alias ls=/bin/ls
fi
```

You're missing the `$` for `$ls_flag` and `-eq` is used for numeric comparison within `[[ ... ]]`

Since "true" and "false" are commands, you want to write

```
if $ls_flag; then
   alias ls=/bin/ls
fi
```

or, more tersely

```
$ls_flag && alias ls=/bin/ls
```

Comment: you are right, my bash scripting knowledge is embarrassing

Answer (score 1):

You could create an alias:

```
alias ls=/bin/ls
```

Comment: this won't work. First because it should be `alias ls=/bin/ls` but even correcting this if I `which ls` I get `/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin/ls`

Comment: And if you type `ls` what happens?  Using `which` is beside the point.

Comment: if I type `ls -@` I get the error showing that I'm still using the GNU ls. But if I do an alias in the local shell then it will work. The problem comes from defining the alias in the bash_profile. Isn't there a clean way to tell to export PATH but the ls command?

Comment: This is the only way I can think of.

Comment: ok, the problem comes from other alias I do to the ls, I'll update the question