# Having trouble setting solarized colorscheme on my MAC terminal and Vim

Tags: linux, macos, vim

I have searched the Internet and tried many ways, but I still have no idea what went wrong.

Here's what I do to install solarized colorscheme.

1.Download package from  https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized

2.Doulbe click the Solarized Dark ansi.terminal file and my terminal looks good.

3.replace my default BSD ls with GNU ls(by installing coreutils)

4.move the solarized.vim to ~/vim/colors

5.modify the .vimrc file(adding the following lines):

```
syntax enable
set background=dark
set t_Co=256
let g:solarized_termcolors=256
colorscheme solarized
```

And these are all done in my newly-bought mac with Yosemite 10.10.2
[image: Here's what my vim look like:]

Curiously, when I select all text, it appears to be normal:[image: After selected]

Also, my ls seems abnormal:[image: my ls effect]

I have stuck at this for a long time. Somebody please helps me, I would really appreciate it. And, happy Chinese new year!

Answer (score 0):

@Xingyu, I think your question is not very clear.

Do you mean the selection color in the Terminal clear enough?

As for your `ls` problem I really don't get it. But have a look on [GNU ls from Coreutils missing OS X ACL implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26585868/gnu-ls-from-coreutils-missing-os-x-acl-implementation) I think it can only help.

You should make your screenshot bigger to make it clear to everyone as it's currently not very understandable with the actual size.

Happy new year :)

Comment: The color scheme in my terminal is "solarized dark" now(see in 3rd picture). However, in VIM, the color is like the first picture where we can see the background is black instead of blue(I want it to be blue). And thanks for the link, I'm exploiting it.